# How to find an integrating factor for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I’m not able to find an integrating factor for the next ordinary differential equation:

$$ x + (1-y^{1/2}) \tan{(x-y)} = \left[ x-y^{1/2} \tan{(x-y)} - \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2} \right] y' $$

I know that it must be of the type $m(x)$, $m(y)$, $m(xy)$, or $m(x±y)$. Could anyone help me a little with this?

Comment: Please make the effort to typeset your equation using MathJaX.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry. And ty for arranging it :)

Comment: And why are you trying to find it? "Just because it looks odd" is not a very good reason.

Comment: I’m looking for an integrating factor because, otherwise, I don’t know how to solve it: it is not Bernoulli, Riccati, Clairaut, homogeneous… Is there another way to solve it that I'm note keeping in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \left( x + (1-y^{1/2}) \tan{(x-y)}\right)dx - \left( x-y^{1/2} \tan{(x-y)} - \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2} \right) dy =0$$
In order to simplify the search of integrating factor, change of variable : $\quad t=x-y \quad\to\quad x=y+t \quad\to\quad dx=dy+dt$

$$ \left( y+t + (1-y^{1/2}) \tan(t)\right)(dy+dt) - \left( y+t-y^{1/2} \tan(t) - \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2} \right) dy =0$$
After simplification :
$$ \left(\tan(t) + \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2} \right)dy +\bigg(y+t-(1-\sqrt{y})\tan(t) \bigg)dt =0$$

$$ \left(\sin(t) + \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2}\cos(t) \right)dy +\bigg((y+t)\cos(t)-(1-\sqrt{y})\sin(t) \bigg)dt =0$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}  \left(\sin(t) + \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2}\cos(t) \right) =\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg((y+t)\cos(t)-(1-\sqrt{y})\sin(t) \bigg)=$$
$$=\cos(t)-\frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2}\sin(t) $$

Hence $ \left(\sin(t) + \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2}\cos(t) \right)dy +\big((y+t)\cos(t)-(1-\sqrt{y})\sin(t) \big)dt  $ is a total differential.

$\begin{cases}
\int \left(\sin(t) + \frac{1}{2} y^{-1/2}\cos(t) \right)dy =y\sin(t)+\sqrt{y}\cos(t)+f(t) \\
\int \big((y+t)\cos(t)-(1-\sqrt{y})\sin(t) \big)dt= y\sin(t)+\sqrt{y}\cos(t)+t\sin(t)+g(y)
\end{cases}$

which implies $\quad g(y)=c=$ constant$\quad$ and $\quad f(t)=t\sin(t)+c$.

The solution is expressed on the form of an implicit equation :
$$y\sin(t)+\sqrt{y}\cos(t)+t\sin(t)=C$$
$$y\sin(x-y)+\sqrt{y}\cos(x-y)+(x-y)\sin(x-y)=C$$
$$\sqrt{y}\cos(x-y)+x\sin(x-y)=C$$